# Create a menu dynamically in wpf using sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have found an example somewhere on internet of `creating a menu dynamically using HierarchicalDataTemplate`.

Here is the xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_Client.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ERP_Lite" Height="350" Width="525" 
        WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None">

    <Grid>

        <Grid.Resources>
            <XmlDataProvider x:Key="src" XPath="/myDoc/item">
                <x:XData>
                    <myDoc xmlns="">
                        <item title="One" />
                        <item title="Two">
                            <item title="First Child" />
                            <item title="Second Child" />
                            <item title="Third Child" />
                            <item title="Fourth Child">
                                <item title="First Grand Child" />
                                <item title="Second Grand Child" />
                                <item title="Third Grand Child" />
                            </item>
                        </item>
                        <item title="Three" />
                        <item title="More" />
                    </myDoc>
                </x:XData>
            </XmlDataProvider>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Menu DataContext="{StaticResource src}" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <Menu.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=item}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@title}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </Menu.ItemTemplate>
        </Menu>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The above xaml works perfectly well. Now I would like to create the same thing using SQL Server instead of xml datasource.

So, for that I have created a table and added the data as follows:

```
ID  |  Title                 |   ParentID
----+------------------------+-----------
1   |  One                   |   NULL
2   |  Two                   |   NULL
3   |  Three                 |   NULL
4   |  Four                  |   NULL
5   |  First Child           |   2
6   |  Second Child          |   2
7   |  Third Child           |   2
8   |  Fourth Child          |   2
9   |  First Grand Child     |   8
10  |  Second Grand Child    |   8
11  |  Third Grand Child     |   8
```

Now can anybody tell me how do I bind this table's data with Menu?

Note: I am using EntityFramework and MVVM.

**Update**

I am sorry, I have not used your code in this example as I don't understand some things like what is `Model`, `the constructor of Node` and also you are not filling the values in Parent or Children properties, so it's everything out of my bounds and I tried to use a somewhat different approach than you. Although you have used a parameterized constuctor but you never supply values to constructor, so I really felt it hard.

Here is what I have tried:

Here is my model class for MenuItem:

```
public partial class MenuItem
{
    public MenuItem()
    {
        this.MenuItems1 = new HashSet<MenuItem>();
    }

    public int MenuItemID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MenuItem> MenuItems1 { get; set; }
    public virtual MenuItem MenuItem1 { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Data Transfer Object that I created for MenuItem class to solve the circular reference error :

```
public class MenuItemDTO
{
    public int MenuItemID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentID { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the method that I have used in WCF service:

```
public IEnumerable<MenuItemDTO> GetAllMenuItems()
{
    using (Entities db = new Entities())
    {
        return (from m in db.MenuItems
                select new MenuItemDTO
                {
                    MenuItemID = m.MenuItemID,
                    Title = m.Title,
                    ParentID = m.ParentID
                }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Here is my MainWindowViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : MainViewModel
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ERP_Lite_ServiceClient client = new ERP_Lite_ServiceClient();

        Parents = new ObservableCollection<MenuItemDTO>
                        (client.GetAllMenuItems().Where(m => m.ParentID == null));
        Children = new ObservableCollection<MenuItemDTO>
                         (client.GetAllMenuItems().Where(m => m.ParentID != null));

        client.Close();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MenuItemDTO> _parents;
    public ObservableCollection<MenuItemDTO> Parents
    {
        get
        {
            return _parents;
        }
        set
        {
            _parents = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Parents");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MenuItemDTO> _children;
    public ObservableCollection<MenuItemDTO> Children
    {
        get
        {
            return _children;
        }
        set
        {
            _children = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Children");
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the xaml:

```
<Menu ItemsSource="{Binding Parents}">
    <Menu.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Service:MenuItemDTO}" 
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemTemplate>
</Menu>
```

But I have got some problem with my code. In output I get all the Parent Items but no child items are displayed. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to work with `HierarchicalDataTemplate` your *ViewModel* needs to be hierarchical too. which means `ItemsSource` inside `HierarchicalDataTemplate` is relative to that node. but in your code you've defined *Parent* and *Children* in the same *ViewModel*,

Think of `MenuItemDTO` as one random node in the tree, so it should have some children with the same type (`MenuItemDTO`).

if you set the `ItemsSource` of `Menu` to `"{Binding Parents}"` it means top level items of the Menu are Parents.

Now if you set the `ItemsSource` of the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` to `"{Binding Children}"`, it can find the children of that node, by looking at its own `ItemsSource`. which should be set for each node in the tree.

### Solution:

Move `Children` to `MenuItemDTO`.

then you might need to modify `GetAllMenuItems()` a little.

Try the code below (it's tested and it works fine). it returns a list of `MenuItemDTO`s that belong to first level of menu, and each has its `Children` filled recursively.

*first level of tree (menu) = menu items with no parent*

```
public IEnumerable<MenuItemDTO> GetAllMenuItems()
{
  using (Entities db = new Entities())
  {
    //get all items and put them in a simple list
    var allItems = (from m in db.MenuItems
                select new MenuItemDTO
                {
                    MenuItemID = m.MenuItemID,
                    Title = m.Title,
                    ParentID = m.ParentID
                }).ToList();

    //define another list and put "only" root items in it
    //  this will have a hierarchical structure (By correcting the Children)
    //  and it's the output of this function
    var roots = allItems.Where(x => x.ParentID == null);

    //here we correct Children of each item
    //since both allItems and roots share the same elements (call-by-reference)
    //instead of searching through a tree, simply search through allItems
    foreach (var item in allItems)
    {
      //find the correct parent for current item
      var parent = allItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MenuItemID == item.ParentID);

      //add the item to Children of its parent
      //   by doing this, one single item in both allItems 
      //   and roots (or recursively in roots) will be corrected
      if(parent!=null)
           parent.Children.Add(item);

      //if you don't want to miss any menu item:
      //else roots.Add(item);
    }
    return roots;
  }
}
```